# 403 (request "ORG_REQUIRES_ACCESS_LIST") This organization requires access through an access list of ip ranges

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to configure access to a MongoDB db on Atlas (MongoDB ver6.0) from my AWS organization.

I am facing now the following error while running my terraform code:

```
│ Error: error reading MongoDB Cluster (xxxx-xxx-xxx): GET https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/6467103204b5e028bfeaba66/clusters/xxxx-xxx-xxx: 403 (request "ORG_REQUIRES_ACCESS_LIST") This organization requires access through an access list of ip ranges.
```

Please advise.
Thanks